# Writing Conditional scripts in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I am just starting with Robot Automation.Below is the scenario where I am stuck.

I am having a sort by  on my page which on one click does ascending order and second click does desc order sorting.
I am not sure how to achieve this.

Below is the html code-

```
<div class="sort-plans">
        <a class="button--sort asc" ng-click="toggleOrderByPrice()" ng-class="{'asc': orderByPrice, 'desc': !orderByPrice }"><strong>Sort by</strong> Price</a>
    </div>
```

Able to locate sort by div using this -

```
Click element                ${LOC_ShopPlanTab_sortByPriceLabel}
```

After clicking I can see below changes in class-

```
${LOC_ShopPlanTab_sortByPriceAsc}     xpath = //a[@class='button--sort asc']
${LOC_ShopPlanTab_sortByPriceDesc}    xpath = //a[@class='button--sort desc']
```

How do I put this together to find out if sorting is working or not?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have a column sorted, to verify the sort, grab values from that column and verify if they are greater than or equal, or less than or equal to each other.

The simple logic would be this:

1. Click the element that sorts the column
2. Check the class element to see if it contains value "asc" or "desc".
3. Whichever it contains, grab at least 2 price values from that column(preferably one from first row, one from a few rows down).
4. You  might have to do some data cleaning (regex) to get the value into an integer or number format, removing dollar signs, commas, etc).
5. Depending on the sort flag (asc or desc) do a compare on the numbers.  If asc, verify that value from 1st row is less than or equal to value in 2nd row. if desc, verify that value from 1st row is greater than or equal to value in 2nd row.

Here's a sample for checking a descending sort.   first line checks to see if column is sorted by descending, then grabs 3 values from the result set (1st, 2nd, 3rd row), converts them to integers, then compares them.

```
Wait Until Element Is Visible    css=th.right.sortdsc > a.ajax-table
${Val1}    Get Text    css=td.right
${Val2}    Get Text    //table[@id='resultsTable']/tbody/tr[2]/td[4]
${Val3}    Get Text    //table[@id='resultsTable']/tbody/tr[3]/td[4]
${V1}    String Convert To Integer    ${Val1}
${V2}    String Convert To Integer    ${Val2}
${V3}    String Convert To Integer    ${Val3}
Should Be True    ${V1} >= ${V2}
Should Be True    ${V2} >= ${V3}
```

Klendathu

Comment: This is a really good solution - it actually checks for values in rows which is much more reliable than classes.